# Multiple "preferred" browsers - spawning certain browsers for certain 'regions' (XP)

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet, browser, google-chrome

I would like to be able to split my preferred browsers in Windows XP so that IE opens some sites (external), and Firefox opens all others (internal).

Is there a way to do this in Windows XP?

Comment: Define "external" and "internal".

Comment: @Hello71 - internet and intranet: external, and internal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Firefox as your main browser and install the [IE Tab Plus add-on](http://coralietab.mozdev.org/) (formerly Coral IE Tab).

This add-on allows you to define URLs for which IE will be used, you will then get a new tab which uses IE for rendering the page.

Works fine for things like http://update.microsoft.com/ or the Outlook Web Interface.